# "Error invoking method check" when deploying a WAR on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, war

When I deploy my WAR generated with Ant on my local system (copy/paste under /webapps), everything works fine.

The thing is, when I deploy the WAR on a remote server for test purposes, I got this error message:

> There was an error thrown by Tomcat during deployment: "Error invoking method check". This however may not mean that you application failed to deploy. Please check the status in the application list

But the application is not deployed at all.
I have to use Probe (lambaprobe.org) to manage and deploy applications on Tomcat on the remote server I'm talking. And I don't have access to the filesystem, only probe.

Any idea would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Impossible to check the log... We managed to restart tomcat and it works now.
Weird.

Thank you anyway!

Comment: This is happening to me now, too, I believe it is because the JVM ran out of memory (error in logs).

Answer (score 4):

I often encountered this problem and after checking the log this was caused by an OutOfMemoryError with tomcat

Answer (score 1):

Check the log files of tomcat; they contain the full error message.

If you can't access them easily, write a small webapp which allows you to browse and/or download the logs and deploy that.